# Invocation of table from mysql is not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

My adapter works fine but cant able to invoke in client side code. I have created a button and if I click it should display the database table.

Yes I have copied this code from other blog but modified here so need help.

```
<html>
<head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>vikdemodb</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <div id="header">
            <h1>database demo</h1>
        </div>          
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="button" id="databasecon" value="click me to get data from db" /><br />

        </div>          

            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

my main.js

```
function wlCommonInit(){



        $('#databasecon').click(loadSQLRecords);


}
function loadSQLRecords(){
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'vikadap',
        procedure : 'getstudinfo',
        parameters : []
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : loadSQLQuerySuccess,
        onFailure : loadSQLQueryFailure
    });
}

function loadSQLQuerySuccess(result){
    console.log("Retrieve success" + result);
console.log(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
}

function loadSQLQueryFailure(result){
    WL.Logger.error("Retrieve failure");
}
```

My adapter implementation

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from studentinfo");
function getstudinfo() {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

here my adap.xml

```html
<wl:adapter name="vikadap"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:sql="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/sql">

    <displayName>vikadap</displayName>
    <description>vikadap</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
            <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

            <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:***/***</url>
                <user>****</user>
                <password>****</password> 
            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getstudinfo"/>
```

Comment: 1) You did not provide all of your all. Edit the question and also provide the displayFeeds function. 2) Open Chrome > new tab. Also open Chrome DevTools. Preview your app in this window. Open the devtools' console and check what error you are getting there.

Comment: actually @idan it is not showing any error .if i click button nothing popsup

Comment: Then like I said, *provide your full implementation*.

Comment: actually idan it doent show any error msgs also it doesnt display the table.can u see any error on my html and main.js code pls ??thnks in advance

Comment: Why do you not read? Again: *provide your full implementation*.

Comment: added my adap.xml thats all my full implementation

Comment: No, it's not. Where is displayFeeds?

Comment: sorry sir what is displayfeed

Comment: Are you serious? Did you even really write this code? Look at your own source code. You have this:  displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.resultSet); -- where is this function in your code?!

Comment: Well, where is the function?

Comment: sorry idan i have commented that displayfeeds pls tell what code should i place ter to display the table from db

Comment: You copied your code from a different place. Go there again and copy the code back.

Comment: yep i m in a process of learning so help needed .if u wish help me or else leave it sir

Answer (score 0):

I must say that this is quite sad. You copy the entire "implementation" from elsewhere, but do not copy the one thing that will finish it - displaying the data that is retrieved by the adapter. Then, you ask a question how to do it... I don't know what is your end goal with your project, but I don't think you'll get there if you will continue like this.

One way you could display the result is a function like this:

```
function displayFeeds(items){
         var ul = $('#itemsList');
         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
              var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].sid);
              li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].sname));
              li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].sgrade));
              li.append($('<hr>'));
              ul.append(li);
        }
}
```

This function assumes there is a UL in your HTML, and then appends LI's into it with items.

You will need to change this to fit your table design, as well as change `sid`, `sname` and `sgrade` with the correct property names from your database.

Next time you copy, at least copy everything: http://javatechig.com/ibm-worklight/invoking-adapter-procedure-in-ibm-worklight

Comment: sir so sorry but i have the above code .actually i did a edit and i have two rows in my  db and i dont have an ul in html

Comment: You do not have the above code. LOOK AT THE CODE THAT YOU HAVE PASTED IN THE QUESTION. IT IS NOT THERE. *CHANGE IT TO FIT YOUR TABLE IN THE HTML! ADD YOUR QUESTION TO THE QUESTION!!!*

Comment: hmm i saw the code and im learning and modifying it in my way just a small mitstake displayfeed which i added unknowingly in my code.

Comment: anyway a huge thanku i am not getting what i want thnk u

Comment: help needed plz anyone

Comment: i dont want for list i want it for button click